# getting value from user in form's text field html

Tags: html

Getting value in text field and when i click on button it should multiply value by 2 and show result in an other text field.Is it possible?

Here is what i am trying in my code but didn't work!

```
<title>    Task 1    </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function multi()
 {
    var temp   =   document.getElementById('number').value;
    temp   =   temp   *   2;
    return    temp;
 }
</script>
```

Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you need ? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86n43eoh/1/)

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="5">  
<input type="button"  value="Double !" onClick="multi()">
<br />
result : <input type="text" id="result" value="">

function multi(value)
{
    var temp   =   document.getElementById('number').value;
    temp   =   temp   *   2;
    document.getElementById('result').value = temp;
}
```

Edit : Forgot to put result on another input, it should be now what you requested

Answer (score 0):

Something like that...
http://jsbin.com/xequzu/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <title>    Task 1    </title>
  <input type='text' id='number'>
  <input type='text' id='result'>
  <button onClick='multi()'>Multi</button>
</body>
</html>

function multi()
{
document.getElementById('result').value = 
    document.getElementById('number').value*2;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets start by talking about event handlers.

The JavaScript browser environment recognizes *events* which include bits of user interaction (clicks, mouseovers, keystrokes...) as well as document loading, property changes, audio and video processing events and just about anything else that occurs in a browser.

You can use JavaScript to register "event handlers." A handler is a function that is tied to an event, and is executed when the event occurs. So, for example, you can register a handler function that handles a click on a specific element. That function will fire whenever the user clicks that element.

There are two ways to register event handlers (well, two common ones). You can either do it in the html by using the various onEvent attributes. That looks like this

HTML:

```
<div id="SayHelloButton" onClick="sayHello"></div>
```

JS:

```
var sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello!");
};
```

The other way is by using one of the various DOM element selector functions (getElmementById, getElementsByName etc...) to select the element or elements for which you wish to register the handler and register it in code. Like so

HTML

```
<div id="SayHelloButton"></div>
```

JS:

```
var sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello!");
};
document.getElementById("SayHelloButton").onclick = sayHello
```

Now let's talk about how getElementById works. You may have noticed that my html tag had an ID attribute. Putting an ID element on an attribute more or less says "This id is the unique identifier for this element so that my javascript code can find it and use it. The getElementById function... well... gets an element by id. If there's no id, it's not gonna find it.

Third, let's talk a bit about input fields. Input fields are used for handling user input. Each input field will have an associated value attribute that can be accessed via JavaScript. For text input fields, this will be the string the user has entered into the field. Other input types work differently. You can look them up on Wikipedia, or Mozilla Developer Network, or wherever

Input fields should only be used for user input. If you just want to display some text, you're better off using a span, div, paragraph or other read-only element. So you really don't want to show the value of one text field in another text field, as a rule.

Finally, let's talk about he innerHtml attribute of tags. Most html elements in JavaScript will expose an innerHtml property which represents the html included "inside" that tag so if you have

```
<div id="myDiv"><p>Spam, Spam, Eggs, Spam</p></div>
```

And

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var inner = myDiv.innerHtml
```

inner will be equal to

```
"<p>Spam, Spam, Eggs, Spam</p>"
```

Now let's put that together for you case.

HTML:

```
<!-- it is best practice to usually store your javascript in external files and reference them like this -->
<script src="whereveryouarestoringyourjavascriptfile.js" type="text/javascript></script>
<!-- Note that the id tells you what the input does -->
<input id="numberToMultiply" type="text"/>
<button type="button" id="multiplyNumberByTwo">Multiply the number by 2!</button>
<!-- I used a div here, there are many options for displaying and styling your output -->
<div id="resulDisplayField"></div>
```

JS:

```
 //Define a multiply by two function (it may seem silly to pull it out here, but start writing complex event handlers and you will be happy you got into the habit of writing lots of little separate functions.
 var multiplyByTwo = function(number) {
        return number * 2
     };
window.onload = function() {
      //Register a click handler for the button.
     document.getElementById("multiplyNumberByTwo").onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("resultDisplayField").innerHtml = String(multiplyByTwo(document.getElementById("numberToMultiply").value))
```

Note that for your use case, this is a ridiculously over-engineered solution. However, as you find yourself designing more complex applications, you will *very* quickly want to start writing code that is more modular and self-documenting, even if it takes longer to write. If you ever work with other developers, believe me, they will thank you.